# C# out parameter value passing

Tags: c#, parameters, out

I am using `contactsreader.dll` to import my Gmail contacts. One of my method has the `out` parameter. I am doing this:

```
Gmail gm = new Gmail();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string strerr;
gm.GetContacts("chendur.pandiya@gmail.com", "******", true, dt, strerr);
// It gives invalid arguments error..
```

And my Gmail class has

```
public void GetContacts(string strUserName, string strPassword,out bool boolIsOK,
out DataTable dtContatct, out string strError);
```

Am I passing the correct values for `out` parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass them as declared variables, with the `out` keyword:

```
bool isOk;
DataTable dtContact;
string strError;
gm.GetContacts("chendur.pandiya@gmail.com", "******",
    out isOk, out dtContact, out strError);
```

In other words, you don't pass values to these parameters, they receive them on the way `out`. One way only.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put "out" when calling the method - `gm.GetContacts("chendur.pandiya@gmail.com", "******", out yourOK, out dt, out strerr);`

And by the way, you don't have to do `DataTable dt = new DataTable();` before calling.
The idea is that the `GetContacts` method will initialize your `out` variables.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(VS.71).aspx) to `MSDN` tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Since the definition of your function

```
public void GetContacts(string strUserName, string strPassword, out bool boolIsOK, out DataTable dtContatct, out string strError);
```

requires that you pass some `out` parameters, you need to respect the method signature when invoking it

```
gm.GetContacts("<username>", "<password>", out boolIsOK, out dtContatct, out strError);
```

Note that `out` parameters are just placeholders, so you don't need to provide a value before passing them to the method. You can find more information about `out` parameters on the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you pass a bool variable instead of a literal value and place the out keyword before them.

```
bool boolIsOK = true;
gm.GetContacts("chendur.pandiya@gmail.com", "******", out boolIsOK, out dt, out strerr)
```